# Can't create handler inside thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare(); Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I am making an timer app. I did some google search and found that WorkManager is a great tool for long running tasks and it is easier to show notifications to the user also. And as I use Jetpack Compose to create the app it would be even compatible and reliable.

I have a `ViewModel` named `TimerViewModel`, which defines and starts the timer. Then for the purpose of extending the `Worker` class I have a kotlin class called `TimerWorker`. Here's how it looks like.

```kt
class TimerWorker(
    private val context: Context,
    private val workerParams: WorkerParameters
):CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams){
    private val timerViewModel: TimerViewModel = TimerViewModel(context.applicationContext as Application)
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        createNotfication()
        timerViewModel.startCountDown() 
        return Result.success()
    }

    // Creates a notification
    private suspend fun createNotfication() {
        setForeground(
            ForegroundInfo(
                Random.nextInt(),
                NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "timerChannel")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setContentText("Timer running...")
                    .setContentTitle("Time is unknown")
                    .build()
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Then in the `TimerViewModel` I define the work request as follows. I also
get the work info to control the main application.

```kt
private val outputWorkInfo: LiveData<List<WorkInfo>>
private val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(getApplication())

init{
    outputWorkInfo = workManager.getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData("timer")
}
val state = outputWorkInfo

//... 

fun runTimer(){ // To start the worker
    val timerRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<TimerWorker>().build()
    workManager.beginUniqueWork(
        "timer",
        ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,
        timerRequest
    ).enqueue()
}
```

And then in the `MainActivity` I call this function as a button `onClick()`. Note that before starting the timer I get the selected time from the protodata store. I guess that it's not relavent to this question.

```kt
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.size(//...),
            onClick = {
                if(savedSecond != null)
                    timerViewModel.modifyTime(TimerViewModel.Companion.TimeUnit.SEC, savedSecond ?: 0)
                timerViewModel.modifyTime(TimerViewModel.Companion.TimeUnit.MIN, savedMinute ?: 0)
                timerViewModel.modifyTime(TimerViewModel.Companion.TimeUnit.HOUR, savedHour ?: 0)

                if(!((secs.value ?: 0) == 0 && (minutes.value ?: 0) == 0 && (hours.value ?: 0) == 0)){
                    if(!isRunning){
                        timerViewModel.runTimer()
                    }
                }
            },
            shape = CircleShape,
        ){//...}
```

My problem is when I touch the `Start` button I get the following error.

```
E/WM-WorkerWrapper: Work [ id=2b4306ff-3f65-4ed6-b1b9-70167fcacaba, tags={ com.example.timer.TimerWorker } ] failed because it threw an exception/error
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:311)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:227)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:129)
        at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:129)
        at android.os.CountDownTimer.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:129)
        at com.example.timer.CountDownTimer.TimerViewModel$startCountDown$1.<init>(TimerViewModel.kt:63)
        at com.example.timer.CountDownTimer.TimerViewModel.startCountDown(TimerViewModel.kt:63)
        at com.example.timer.TimerWorker.doWork(TimerWorker.kt:19)
        at com.example.timer.TimerWorker$doWork$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

It would be grateful if you could explain what causes the error and a fix for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really sorry for bothering and being dumb. I just got to know that `ViewModel`s can't be instantiated a `Worker`.

Besides `WorkManager` is not meant for Timers. As for the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#stop-worker);

> The system instructed your app to stop your work for some reason. This can happen if you exceed the execution deadline of 10 minutes. The work is scheduled for retry at a later time.